# Validate existence of submodel in 'has_one' relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, has-one

I have two models, one `Post` and `Genre`. I'm creating new post with given `genre_id`. What is the best way of validating if genre with given id exists? For now I'm validating presence of genre_id, but it's not enough.

`validates :genre_id, presence: true`

I know I can check whether the genre exists in a controller, but I would prefer to have this in my post validator object.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html. 

You should be able to do the following:

    validates :genre_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true. Custom validation object with ActiveModel::Validator is probably overkill for uniqueness, since you're going to have to write your own validator to search through the table for a matching genre id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly tell Rails to validate the `genre` association and not just the attribute, `genre_id` with:

```
has_one :genre 
validates_presence_of :genre
```

[validates_presence_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of)